# Find registry key and only save value if it exist

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I need to a find if a registry key exist and only save value if it exist.  I am not getting anything in the variable KeyValue.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayexpansion
set KEY="HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome"
for /f "tokens=3*" %%A in ('reg query %KEY% /v installocation') do set InstallLocation=%%A %%B
If ERRORLEVEL 0 set KeyValue = InstallLocation
echo %KeyValue%
cmd /k
```

I get "ECHO is on." instead of the value.  I think the variable is empty

Comment: You cannot save a value from a key which doesn't exist, so what's your problem? Other than that, why are you enabling delayed expansion? and specifically checking in that location? You do not use `set` like that, please open a Commandf Prompt window and enter `set /?` to read how to use the command. Unless the error level is a negative number, `If ERRORLEVEL 0` will always be true! Why don't you check to see if the variable has content/is defined instead? The best way to achieve that is to undefine the variable, run the [tag:for-loop], then check to see if the variable is then defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the ERRORLEVEL handling to a more modern approach (src: https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html).

See the following:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayexpansion
set KEY="HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome"
set INSTALLLOCATION=""
set KEYVALUE=""
for /f "tokens=3*" %%A in ('reg query %KEY% /v installocation') do set %INSTALLLOCATION%=%%A %%B
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 set %KEYVALUE%=%INSTALLLOCATION%
echo %KEYVALUE% 
cmd /k
```

I also modified it so that it won't echo unless there was no failure.

Comment: I need installlocation to be saved to a different variable.

Comment: I modified the code. Note that an empty string will now print every time.

Comment: This is not the correct way of doing this Jordan. You have defined two variables whose content is `""`. That means you would be trying to `set ""=""`. Then you'd print an empty variable, thus returning the same `ECHO is on.` or `ECHO is off.` message as was mentioned in the question, you'd need to `Echo %""%`, and I'm sure that's not what you wanted to do!

Comment: I have downvoted this answer, because of the reasons in my previous comment. Effectively this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick remarked [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example, based upon part of my comment, *(it should require no modification or addition)*.

```batch-file
@Rem Your registry key goes below this line.
@Set "RKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome"
@Rem Below here is where you undefine any existing value for the target variable.
@Set "VData="
@Rem Next you run your registry query, [using the correct spelling].
@For /F "EOL=HTokens=2*" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "%RKey%" /V "InstallLocation" 2>NUL"')Do @Set "VData=%%H"
@Rem Below is where you check to see if a value is now defined for the target. variable.
@If Not Defined VData Echo Data not found.&"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" 3 /NoBreak>NUL&Exit /B 1
@Rem If you got here the value data existed and will be printed in the console.
@Echo %VData%
@Rem The next line was added to ensure that you get to read the printed output.
@Pause
```

You may optionally remove all remark lines, *(those beginning with `@Rem`)*.